# Incremental counts based on group within Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to create an increased increment of the "type" grouped by the [ID], and [Date] columns.

**DATA**

```
ID  Date    type    
AA  Q1.21   hi  
AA  Q1.21   hi  
AA  Q1.21   hello   
AA  Q1.21   ok  
AA  Q1.21   ok  
AA  Q1.21   ok  
AA  Q2.21   hello   
AA  Q2.21   hello   
BB  Q1.21   hi  
BB  Q1.21   hi
```

**DESIRED**

```
ID  Date    type    NEW
AA  Q1.21   hi      hi01
AA  Q1.21   hi      hi02
AA  Q1.21   hello   hello01
AA  Q1.21   ok      ok01
AA  Q1.21   ok      ok02
AA  Q1.21   ok      ok03
AA  Q2.21   hello   hello01
AA  Q2.21   hello   hello02
BB  Q1.21   hi      hi01
BB  Q1.21   hi      hi02
```

**DOING**

```
df['NEW'] = df['type'] + df.groupby([*df]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

However, this is creating a one beside each type and not incrementing based on the Date and ID. I am still researching,
any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add with the `type`, not the `ID`:

```
df['New'] = df['type'] + df.groupby([*df]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```